# Antivirus treats my application as danger

Tags: c++, privileges, antivirus, tray

Sorry for my English on the beginning.

A wrote an application for Windows Vista that communicates with other application on Android. That is how we can control PC using android application. PC side application was written as an console application and it works proper. The problem begins when I decided to hide console window:

```
HWND hWnd = GetConsoleWindow();
ShowWindow( hWnd, SW_HIDE );
```

After that, AVG antivirus started to treat this appliaction as danger. I tried to solve this by adding to my application tray icon. Unfortunately it doesn't help. I also tried make my application as windows service, but this service doesn't get privileges to some tasks.

I don't know what to do now, please help.

Comment: Probably your antivirus believes that hiding windows is suspicious, which it can be.

Comment: @ChrisChambers It can be, but it's hardly indicative - plenty of applications hide windows and it's perfectly acceptable behavior. I suspect *more* is going on here. C D, you may want to reach out of the AVG folks (if indeed your application is **not** a virus) and submit your application as an instance where AVG heuristics fail. You may also want to see if digitally signing your application affects the behavior of AVG.

Comment: @NikBougalis Not saying that I agree with it, just saying that some antivirus programs are a little overprotective.

Comment: @NikBougalis I agree with Chris. This method of hiding windows is often a "Shortcut", It is usually better to destroy the window, recreating it as necessary.

Comment: @Senjai nonsense - there are perfectly good reasons to keep a window around but hidden. MFC socket handling, for example, relies on such a hidden window. System notification icons rely on such hidden windows. And so on, and so forth.

Comment: I tried with Win32App without console. Instead of hiding window, I just don't create it. It doesn't matter for AVG. I suspect, the problem for AVG is because there is no window AND application takes control on mouse. I could send it to AVG, but what if other anti-virus software works similar? Tomorrow I'll try with this digitally signing, but I have a bad suspicions, because virus can be also signed.

Comment: @CD Can you post your feedback? I have the same problem. What did solve it? Code signing? (was it expensive?)

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend you change your application to a Win32 application. The differences should be fairly minimal: Defining `WinMain` instead of `main` is probably the most significant. Win32 subsystem applications do not by default have a console.

Comment: Ahh, *excellent* catch. I didn't notice that the OP was trying to hide the console. +1.

Comment: Unfortunately AVG still treats this as a danger. Instead of hiding window, I just don't create it. It doesn't matter for AVG. Probably it recognized it as a danger not only because there is no window. The problem for AVG is there is no window AND application takes control on mouse.

Comment: Perhaps complain to AVG support? This is AVG's problem, not yours. Perhaps ask them what you need to do to not trigger the AV. Perhaps they will whitelist your application. They may also suggest something such as signing your cod.